# non-square picture dimensions for a LaTeXiT circle

Tags: tikz-pgf, circles, latexit

Running the following in LaTeXiT

preamble:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[usenames]{color} %used for font color
\usepackage{amssymb} %maths
\usepackage{amsmath} %maths
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %useful to type directly diacritic characters
\usepackage{tikz}
```

body

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw  (1.5,1.5) circle [radius=1.5];
\end{tikzpicture}
```

produced the following picture

[image]

When I right-clicked on it, and chose "Get Info" it says that it has dimensions 618 × 620. My questions are:

- how come such a symmetric shape resulted in uneven dimensions?
- Is there a way to predict the image dimensions from the TikZ parameters (e.g. `radius`)?
- Is there a natural way to get a circle with equal dimensions in TikZ?

Thanks.

Comment: `\newbox\msbox\setbox\msbox=\hbox{\begin{tikzpicture}\draw (1.5,1.5) circle [radius=1.5];\end{tikzpicture}}\typeout{width:\the\wd\msbox,height:\the\ht\msbox,depth:\the\dp\msbox}` produces `width:85.75821pt,height:85.75821pt,depth:0.0pt` in the log. How does LaTeXiT calculate the dimensions for the "Get Info"? And what are the units?

Comment: @MarkWibrow Thanks for the code. Unfortunately I can't run it neither on LaTeXiT not ShareLaTeX. As for your question, that is what I've tried to ask on the second bullet point. The units in the dimensions appear to be pixels.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). A MWE should compile and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. it's much easier to help you if we have full working code to start from. This said, I'm fairly confident, especially given Mark's comment, that the  dimensions of the tikz circle are correct. The problem almost certainly with "Get Info" and/or LaTeXIt. It may also be browser dependent.

Comment: @Andrew As far as LaTeXiT is concerned, I believe this is a MWE. I haven't tried getting the image out of a dedicated LaTeX editor yet. I want to try that and see if the problem persists.

Comment: A [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) should be a single piece of compilable code. You have given a couple of code snippets that can be assembled, with some extra bits of code, so that they compile. The easier that it is for people to help you the more likely that some one will...

Comment: @user1337 just add `\box\msbox` to the end. The error results (I assume) from there being no content

Comment: This is (I think) do with how LaTeXiT calculates the bounding box, which (again I think) is based on the output of PDFCrop.